# How to make rigid body flying

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

Usually setting object with rigid body active will go down, is it possible to object go flying up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.*Turn off [gravity](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/forces/gravity.html#gravity) in the scene settings.*

2.Now, add an *active rigid body* object and change the mass to something very small, like `.003kg` (this may need to be adjusted later)

3.Add a [*wind* force field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/forces/force_fields/types/wind.html#wind) at the center of the scene (or origin of *passive object*) (make sure direction of wind is correct for your scene)

---

At this point things should be roughly working, so adjust the *strength* of the wind force against the *mass* of the active rigid body until the simulation is satisfactory.

Wind settings used in example gif are below:

### [image]

Very basic example below:
[image]